# Can I install postgresql without pgAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql, nsis, pgadmin

I was packaging an windows application installer by NSIS.

An postgresql binary file was included in this install package.

But the official binary file is too large 172MB.

The zip archive is  download from
https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries

The inside structure is like

pgsql

- bin
- doc
- include
- lib
- pgAdmin4
- share
- StackBuilder
- symbols

In my opinion, pgAdmin4 is no need for my installer.

There are only CRUD operations in between application and SQL.

If I remove this directory, the binary zip can down to 41MB.

So could I simply remove directory pgAdmin4 and re-compress
to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So could I simply remove directory pgAdmin4 and re-compress to achieve this?

Yes, and you can remove StackBuilder too if you want. Also `symbols` if you don't want to do in-place debugging if the postgres server crashes.

Please, **please** install your bundled PostgreSQL on a *non-default port*  (not 5432) and if you run it as a service use a name associated with your application, so users know where it came from. See [Installation of postgresql with NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24625490/398670) . Put the PostgreSQL install directory within your app install directory.

Comment: Thanks! Craig. 
Yes, I  had see that article before.  It help me a lot before I build my NSIS installer.